# How to implement 'phonetic typing' for performing a language conversion of a field (using CKEditor)?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I am using CKEditor in a Drupal website. I am looking for a technique to **convert** (not **translate**) words from English to some other language (say Telugu), while typing those words.

Below are 2 examples to illustrate *Phonetic typing* (during the creation of a node):

1. If I start with typing "*What*" in a text-area (long text), then it should suggest something like so:

   [image: Sample using 'what']
2. If I then continue typing "*oka*" in a text-area (long text), then it should suggest something like so:

   [image: Sample using 'oka'] ... 2

How can I achieve (implement) this while using CKEditor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a module called [Indic Script](https://drupal.org/project/indic_script).

> This Module enables IME (Transliteration Input Method) for Indian Languages in Drupal Text Fields and Text Area Fields So that users can create their content in their own Language within Drupal without installing any additional software.
>
> 6.x-3.0 and 7.x-2.x version has the integration for CKEditor ([CKEditor.module](https://drupal.org/project/ckeditor) and [WYSIWYG.module](https://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg))
>
> Indic Script module supports Type writer (TW) as well as Phonetic typing
>   for the following languages.
>
> - Tamil, Tamil Tw, Tamil 99
> - Hindi, Hindi Tw, Hindi Remington Tw
> - Malayalam, Malayalam Tw
> - Bengali, Unijoy, Bengali Tw
> - Gujarati, Gujarati Tw
> - Kannada, Kannada Tw
> - Oriya, Oriya Tw
> - Punjab, Punjab Tw
> - Telugu, Telugu Tw & Telugu Apple Tw

I've tested this module. Here is the screenshot of this module usage with CK field

[image]

I hope it helps someone.

Comment: Can i know for which version of CKEditor and Indic script the above screenshot belongs? Because when i tried, the language selection option appeared for me only with the Plain Text Editor.

Comment: Thanks @shasi :) This supports Drupal Text Fields and Text Area Fields also. The latest version of CKEditor works (Infact I don't remember the version of that module ;) )

Comment: Ok, so do i need to configure CKEDitor module with Indic Script module? I don't find any settings that map both of them.

Comment: @shasi Sorry for delay. Have you got it. There is a configuration setting for that. I think at  admin/settings/indic_script

Comment: It is under: admin/config/content/indic_script. I saw that there is only option for choosing languages and typing methods, but nothing about Ckeditor integration. Even in the CKEditor settings, there is no setting for Indic script.

Comment: @shasi I don't remember the exact configuration. If you want me look into that I'll :) but please go through the README.txt file. and make sure to give permissions to the user to use Indic script.

Comment: Well, I figured it out. Actually i had to copy the ckeditor plugin of Indic Script module (sites\all\modules\indic_script\kanni\plugins\ckeditor\kanni) to the plugins folder of CKEditor module (sites\all\modules\ckeditor\plugins). Then i have to go to the CK Editor Configuration and edit the Full and Advanced profiles to enable the Indic script plugin under EDITOR APPEARANCE. Then finally i could see the Language selection option for the text area field.